# Stripe enable Paypal disable pay later

Tags: javascript, paypal, stripe-payments, payment

The Stripe docs say buy now pay later is also immediate:
[https://stripe.com/en-de/guides/payment-methods-guide#:~:text=Delayed-,Buy,-now%2C%20pay%20later](https://stripe.com/en-de/guides/payment-methods-guide#:%7E:text=Delayed-,Buy,-now%2C%20pay%20later)

But it increases risk for fraud and I assume that is also the type where u have to handle the checkout.session.async_payment_failed/succeeded. Which isn't quite the thing I want in my buy the product once business.

Can I somehow disable those in stripe but allow the parent like paypal and klarna, but not their pay later options?

Or does paypal/klarna deposit the money immediately (which would explain the immediate in the docs)

Comment: yes, it does explain the immediate in the docs

Comment: You can manage/disable some payment methods in your dashboard (if you are using automatic payment methods)
https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/payment_methods
or explicitly specify which payment method you want to use:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-payment_method_types

Comment: Between, checkout.session.async_payment_failed/succeeded are for delayed payment methods (like bank debit) and not for Paypal/Klarna

Answer (score 1):

To the receiving account, a Pay Later payment is *identical* to a "PayPal" payment. You will not see any difference, nor be informed when a customer ended up using the Pay Later funding source. The agreement and collection is between the payer and PayPal only.

The Pay Later funding source is also accessible through the normal "PayPal" button -- so, having a separate Pay Later button effectively just serves to expose it earlier in the flow to customers who may be more likely to check out if they see the offer available.